# IntelliJ IDEA folders instead of packages in project view

Tags: view, intellij-idea, package, directory

Is it possible in IntelliJ IDEA to show folders instead of packages in project view? There is such a feature in Eclipse: we can just switch from "package explorer" to "project explorer" and here we go.

To make it more clear:

I want to see packages as hierarchy of folders.

I wanna see this:
[image]

but instead I see this:

[image]

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes you can switch "View as" from Packages to Project.

[image: Packages]

[image: Project]

For expanding folders uncheck Compact Empty Middle Packages

[image]

Comment: Try uncheck Compact Empty Middle Packages. I think you will get what you need.

Answer (score 21):

Simple, follow these steps and you should able to resolve the issue

[image: Step 1]

Then

[image: Step 2]

Done :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by going to options menu, please follow the below images.( This is not that much useful)

[image: Options menu]
[image: One]
[image]
[image: Three]