# How can i rename my package? IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I try to upload my App into the Play Store, but Google does not allow Apps which contain packages with names like: "example.xxxxx".
My problem is that my package is called "com.example.MainActivity" and I already tried to rename it, but all I can do with IntelliJ is renaming the part "MainActivity". "example" remains the same. After trying to change example by going into the manifest and refactoring it with a different name, IntelliJ just created a new package with the new name, but the old package, which is in use, still has got the same name. 
Could anybody help me with this problem and tell me how to change the package name correctly?

Edit:
The Manifest and R files did not get copied, after renaming example. Could anybody help me how to include them? 
Edit2: I solved the problem with both files by just changing the package name inside the AndroidManifest.xml file. 
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: First uncheck Compact Empty Middle Packages, then Right Click on the package in the package explorer to the left (normally) and choose Refactor > Rename. Done. Be careful to check that in the manifest it is well renamed, sometimes it doesn't refactor there.

**Uncheck Compact Empty Middle Packages**
[image: Uncheck]

**Should look like those packages**

[image: Packages]

**Rename package**

[image: Rename]

The warning will still appear, but you should be able to rename the package.

Comment: I already tried that. 
After i click on Rename a warning opens up:
Rename package or Rename directory.
When i choose Rename package, i can only rename the part AFTER "example" 
e.g.: Change "MainActivity" to "NewName"
After that it would be: "example.NewName"

Comment: I was able to rename and refactor "example" now, but the files inside MainActivity(R and Manifest) did not get copied. I will include a screenshot in my post.

Comment: The option to compact/list single package names can be found under the settings 'wheel' *in* the package explorer.

Answer (score 3):

Less hassle version of this action is simply to open some class and get to the package and click <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> or select appropriate position from context menu:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rename empty middle package you should first expand package tree.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10412589/2305175) is nice (though a bit outdated) example how to do that. 
Then you'll be able to rename desired package with refactor->rename.

Comment: Please correct comment to include directions, not a link that may go stale.

Comment: 1) What do you mean under “direction” and how to do that?
2) How could linked page can change? Question I pointed at is answered about 2 years ago and unlikely to change. Moreover I linked not to another unreliable site, but to stackoverflow. 
3) and most important – my answer directly says what to do in this particular case and how to resolve it. Where is minus came from? For bad style? You should instead provide concrete links (oh, i forget, "directions" or anything else) to stackoverflow guidelines to help me learn.